# "Stand Out For", "Stand Out Because Of"

Tags: prepositional-phrases

I have a substitution question about the phrase "*stand out*" [here](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/11/18/nyregion/a-review-of-coals-in-port-chester.html?_r=0):

> A daily pizza special was a witty combo of asiago, Grana Padano, spicy bresoala, jammy tomatoes, lemon oil and lots of garlic. Two other pizzas ***stood out for*** their forward flavors: the Smokey Joe, made with smoked mozzarella, sweet coppa and red onion, and the Dean Martin, topped with big rounds of pepperoni, sharp pecorino and lots of parsley.

According to defintion 2 of "*stand out*" in this [dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/stand):

> to be better or more important than the other people or things in a group in a way that is easily seen or noticed

So, "*stand out*" loosely means "be better than others".  So, for the sentence:

> 1. Two other pizzas ***stood out for*** their forward flavors.

, if I replaced "*stand out for*" with "*better than others for*", I have:

> 2. Two other pizzas were ***better than others for*** their forward flavors.

Sentence 2 sounds off.  But replacing "*for*" with "*because of*" seems to save the day:

> 3. Two other pizzas were ***better than others because of*** their forward flavors.

But that would bring up a question of whether replacing "*for*" with "*because of*" in sentence 1:

> 4. Two other pizzas *stood out* ***because of*** their forward flavors.

, is better.  Is the "*stand out .... for*"  pattern not as good as "*stand out .... because of*"  pattern?  What do native speakers think?

Comment: *This* native speaker thinks it's largely a matter of personal preference which preposition/conjunction you use after figurative ***stand out***. So *Domino's pizzas stand out **with** their fast delivery service* is fine, as is *Domino's pizzas stand out **for** me **thanks to** their excellent selection of toppings*. In short, it's all a matter of opinion, and mine is that as usual you worry too much about exactly what any given preposition "means" in any given context (***for*** here can imply ***in respect of*** rather than ***because of***, for example).

Comment: "stand out" does not *necessarily* mean "better" or "superior". It means "more prominent", "more easily discerned, noticed, tasted, etc".  They stand out "for their forward flavors". Something can stand out for "sharp flavors" and if one does not like sharpness, then that thing is not better.  And we would say "*the* others" there.

Comment: "because of" is legal, but in terms of frequency of use, "for" is preferred. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stand+out+for%2Cstand+out+because+of&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstand%20out%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstand%20out%20because%20of%3B%2Cc0

Comment: As we can see in this ngram, "stands out for its *lack*" is not low on the list. http://tinyurl.com/pkpypkd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Because of" is equivalent to, but more awkward than, "for" in this usage. However, I would also point out that your substitution of "better than others" in the place of "stood out" is not entirely accurate. Standing out does not necessarily have a positive connotation. Something can stand out in a negative way, also. In this case, the original author clearly meant that the pizzas stood out in a positive way and your substitution would work, but the phrases are not equivalent.